# Lua string manipulatuion

Tags: lua

A string '321@322@323@324@325'.
here number of digits in each number is 3 but it's not limited to 3 it could be any number. 
here are 5 numbers in  a string but this number could be anything. 
task is to get 321,322,323,324,325 and store in a table so that any operation could be performed over them.
I have tried several string functions like c = c:gsub('%W','') to eliminate those non-alphanumeric characters, but nothing helped.

```
function encrypter()--FUNCTION 14
    c=' '
    print('Please enter your message!')
    local message=io.read()
    lengthOfString=string.len(message)--Inbuit function to get length of a string.
    newLine()
    print('Please enter your key. Remember this key, otherwise your message wont be decrypted')
    newLine()
    key=io.read()
    key=tonumber(key)
    largeSpace()
    print("Encrypted message is")
    for s=1,lengthOfString do
        --print(encryptionFormula(string.byte(message,s),key))
        --inbuilt function for converting character of a string to it's respective ASCII value. First place gets character or variable having string whereas second place gets position of that character in the given string.
        b=encryptionFormula(string.byte(message,s),key)
        c=c..tostring(b)..'@'
        --print(c)
        b=0
    end
    print(c)
    largeSpace()
    print("Now share this message along with the key to the receiver. Don't share your key with anyone, if you don't want your message to be read.")
end
```

Comment: `local array = (loadstring or load)("return {"..c:gsub("%W+", ",").."}")()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it didn't solve my issue. Might be I'm not using it correctly. I added the function which generates that string basically it's a encrypter function and it encrypts an user message into some numbers. for ex '123....n@123...n@123...n@......'  Now I want to make a decryptor function but I'm unable to filter those numbers individually from string.

Comment: The numbers are already in `array`.  Just iterate: `local c = ""; for _, b in ipairs(array) do b = decryptionFormula(b, key); c = c..string.char(b) end; print(c)`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`string.gmatch()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch).

```lua
local input = "123@546514@13@548@2315"

local numbers = {}
for number in string.gmatch(input, '%d+') do
   table.insert(numbers, number)
end

-- Output the numbers

for index, number in ipairs(numbers) do
   print(index, number)
   -- This prints:
   -- 1 123
   -- 2 546514
   -- 3 13
   -- 4 548
   -- 5 2315
end
```

If you don't know how Lua patterns work, you can read about them in the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) or you can have a look at [Programming in Lua](http://lua.org/pil) (the first edition is available for free [on their website](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html))

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the solution and reference links.